# how to do not generate jhiPrefix with jhipster

Tags: jhipster

By default, jhiPrefix  is set to `jhi`.
In jdl, I want to set `jhiPrefix no`,but finally I get a `no` prefix.
if I set `jhipster` with no value,I get a error.

Answer (score 1):

`jhiPrefix` is mandatory it's purpose is to avoid problems with reserved keywords.
That said, an empty `jhiPrefix` should be possible using `jhiPrefix ""`.